# Select item in Lightswitch grid when click on custom control

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have Lightswitch app and i have screen with grid there, in each row i have my custom control - image with link to selcted item detail screen , problem is that if i click on that control it doesnt select the row where the control is but it showing detail screen of row which was selected before.. any help ?

```
public void MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  var objDataContext = (IContentItem)this.DataContext;
  var Screen = (Microsoft.LightSwitch.Client.IScreenObject)objDataContext.Screen;

  Screen.Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    Screen.Details.Methods["DoImageLinkEvent"]
          .CreateInvocation(null).Execute();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it !! problem was that i was handling the event on

```
MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseClick"
```

But then item was selected after so now handling it on

```
MouseLeftButtonUp="MouseClick"
```

And it works :)